# How do I get rid of my friend's face?

Tags: face-raiders

In the Home Screen of my Nintendo 3DS, I scroll to the Face Raiders application and see that the face of a friend of mine is still there. That friend played with Face Raiders in June, so is there any way to take the face off the home screen?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The faces on the Face Raiders home screen eyecatch are chosen from the database of faces you have in-game.

While there is no way to mark a face as "do not use for eyecatch", the face will **no longer be used** if **removed** from the game.

Comment: what if I don't want to delete the face?

Comment: @JerryRox Then there will be a chance of the face appearing on the home screen.

Comment: The answer above is wrong. As I have had the same problem, I tried deleting the face and it still appears on the home screen. So, yo might have to delete the face from the camera if it was transported.

Comment: @user80039 It's not wrong. If the face you deleted is still appearing, that's probably just due to caching. Try restarting your 3DS - next time it chooses a face for the eyecatch the one you deleted won't be able to be chosen. Deleting the photo won't do anything at all - it's completely separate from the faces saved to the game.